# Properly typing 'in' expression - The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must not be a primitive

Tags: typescript

I have a bit of React code that is yielding an error: `The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must not be a primitive.`. I am not sure how to properly resolve this:

```
    // I want to allow null, string, object, arrays, etc as may be returned from a request
    type APIGatewaySuccessResponse = unknown

    ...
    const [data, setData] = useState<T>(null)
    ...
    const fetchData = async () => {
      onLoading()
      const data = await sendRequest<T>(route, options) 

      // Checking if object is not enough to get rid of error....
      if (typeof data === 'object' && 'error' in data) {
        setError(data.error)
        onError(data.error)
      } else {
        setData(data)
        onSuccess(data)
      }
     ...
```

Adding the `sendRequest` code for clarity:

```
// Make api request
export const sendRequest = async <T extends APIGatewaySuccessResponse>(
  route: string,
  options?: FetchOptions
): Promise<T | APIGatewayErrorResponse> => {
  const method = options?.method || FetchMethod.POST
  const body = options?.payload ? JSON.stringify(options.payload) : null

  const response = await fetch(route, {
    method,
    headers: {
     ...
    },
    body
  })

  const data = await response.json()

  if (response.ok) {
    return data as T
  } else {
    return data as APIGatewayErrorResponse
  }
}
```

Because I am passing a generic the `in` function throws this error. How can I address issue while maintaining a generic?

Comment: What is `T` as where you call `sendRequest<T>(...)`? Why don't you constrain it to `APIGatewaySuccessResponse`? What is `APIGatewaySuccessResponse` (could it be a primitive)?

Comment: @kellys ah yes  - it's set to `unknown`. Am just not sure how I could have the flexibility of the generic allowing pretty much any kind of response (null, object, string, etc) and have it not be a primitive. What approach would you recommend?

Comment: This likely won't solve your issue, but maybe you should check for `data && typeof data === 'object' && 'error' in data`, considering `data` may be `null` and pass the `object` check.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera ya tried that. Also playing around with using `object | null | string | number` instead of `unknown` as they have in the issue I linked in my answer.  i got it working with a type guard which really just seems to be the same thing except I  cast to `any`. But the error went away...

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure what is going on. I've been reading up on this issue and it appears this example works for people:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43210#issue-829989052 but it throws the error no matter what TS version I use.

I was however able to resolve it using a type guard:

```
export const isError = (response: any): response is APIGatewayErrorResponse => {
  return 'error' in response
}
```

And then:

```
const data = await sendRequest<T>(route, options)
if (isError(data)) {
  setError(data.error)
  onError(data.error)
} else {
  setData(data)
  onSuccess(data)
}
```